# chose row and column value based on condition

Tags: shell

I have a table called `resultat.csv` and it would look like this :

```
  20.7  120.4  -80
 -10.1   78   -155
  5.44  32.4   43.9
```

What I tried to do is :

on each line of `resultat.csv`

```
if the value of the 1st column is less or equal to 0 then you pick the 
value from column 3
```

ELSE

```
if the value of the 1st column is greater than 0 then you pick the 
value from column 2
```

The value of the 1st column is a decimal number that can be negative.

Here my code :

```
 awk -F " " ' {print $1}' resultat.csv | while IFS=, read -r k
do
    status=$(echo "$k <= 0" | bc)

if [[ $status -eq 1 ]];then

grep -- $k resultat.csv | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' 

elif [[ $status -eq 0 ]];then

grep -- $k resultat.csv | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' 

fi

done > Y.csv
```

But it doesn't give error but it doesn't give my expected output

```
120.4
-155
32.4
```

the grep I use doesn't catch the value from the 1st column of `resultat.csv` but all the value what look like.

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: this is the long way around to a one-line `awk` program, but if you want to understand why this code isn't working, paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and be sure to include something like `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. Good luck.

Comment: If you use a `.csv` extension for a file that uses whitespace to separate columns instead of commas, you're just going to confuse people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it all in awk to keep it simple.

```
awk '{ if ($1 > 0) print $2; else print $3 }' resultat.csv
```

Comment: thank you !! How efficient and amazing is your answer, I feel stupid with my 9 lines code.

Comment: @MKF We've all done it! We learn in steps, and shell code has it's place (just not for fixing data files ;-)) Work your way thru the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and you'll be happy you spent the time. Good luck to all.